# How to echo the eloquent relationship between my models( member, campaign and pledge models) respectively on my view/pledge/index page laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

Hello guys how do i echo the eloquent relationship between my models (member, campaign and pledge models respectively) laravel
Here is my campaign model

```
class Campaign extends Model
{
    protected $table = "campaigns";

    public function pledges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pledge::class, 'campaign_id', 'id')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }
}
```

Here is my pledge model

```
class Pledge extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pledges";

    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Campaign::class, 'id', 'campaign_id');
    }


    public function member()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Member::class, 'id', 'member_id');
    }
}
```

Here is my Member Model

```
class Member extends Model
{
    protected $table = "members";

    public function loans()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Loan::class, 'borrower_id', 'id');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
    }

    public function pledges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Pledge::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function contributions()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Contribution::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(MemberTag::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }

    public function attendance()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(EventAttendance::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
    public function families()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(FamilyMember::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
    public function family()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Family::class, 'member_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

Here is my view page for the index.pledge.blade, 
but the campaign->name and member->first_name is not showing on the pledge view page

please guys your feedback would be greatly appreciated

```
<div class="widget-content nopadding">
            <table class="table table-bordered data-table">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Campaign</th>
                  <th>Member</th>
                  <th>Amount</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>


                <tr class="gradeX">
                    @foreach ($pledge as $pledges)
                      <tr>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->campaign ? $pledges->campaign->name : '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->member ? $pledges->member->first_name : '' }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->amount }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $pledges->date }}</td>
                      </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: You might have your keys backwards on `campaign()` and `member()` functions. Also, `$pledge AS $pledges` is grammatically backwards, should it be `$pledges AS $pledge`? Last note, you can do a `dd()` in the controller where `$pledge->campaign` and `$pledge->member` is defined to see what's in those relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<tr class="gradeX">
@foreach ($pledges as $pledge)
<tr>
<td>{{ $pledge->campaign ? $pledge->campaign()->name : '' }}</td>
<td>{{ $pledge->member ? $pledge->member()->first_name : '' }}</td>
<td>{{ $pledge->amount }}</td>
<td>{{ $pledge->date }}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
</tr>
```

Comment: `$pledge->campaign()->name` is an error. You'd need `$pledge->campaign()->first()` there to be able to access `->name`, and this is an extra DB call, which in a loop is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Your defined the wrong inverse relationship into pledged model. It should be belongsTo() method in campaign function of pledged model

```
class Pledge extends Model
{
    protected $table = "pledges";

    public function campaign()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Campaign::class, 'id', 'campaign_id');
    }

    public function member()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Member::class, 'id', 'member_id');
    }
}
```